# Concepts not working for inline class definitions

Tags: c++, nested, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm struggling to understand why the concept isn't satisfied in the following code:

```
#include <concepts>

template <class T> concept has_Default_Constructor = requires (T t)
{
 { T () } -> std::same_as <T>;
};

class A
{
public:
  class B
  {
  public:
    int x = 0;
  };

  static_assert (has_Default_Constructor <B>); // asserts in gcc and clang

  B b;
};
```

This compiles ok in MSVC but not gcc or clang. (All latest versions as of 03-02-2024)

If I move the static_assert outside of class A, it works ok:

```
class A
{
public:
  class B
  {
  public:
    int x = 0;
  };

  B b;
  //static_assert (has_Default_Constructor <B>);
};

static_assert (has_Default_Constructor <A::B>); // does not assert
```

(I can't do this in the actual code because has_Default_Constructor is used in the construction of members in A.)

I'm assuming that the problem is something to do with incomplete (unsized) classes but I don't understand how it applies in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The default member initializers are in a complete-class context and the `noexcept` specification of the implicitly-declared default constructor depends on whether the default member initializers are potentially-throwing.

The complete-class context of a nested class also includes the containing class definition. So the compiler is generally only able to complete the declaration of the default constructor of `B` after the closing brace of the definition of `A`.

I am not sure whether the standard properly specifies the behavior in this specific situation where you use a concept directly. However, you generally get problems of this kind when using type traits on nested classes in the enclosing class definition. The point of instantiation of the type trait will be *before* the namespace scope declaration, i.e. the enclosing class definition, where the nested class can't be complete yet. It has the same problem as using a type trait on a class type in its own definition.

Answer (score 2):

This is [CWG 1397](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1397) which seems to intend to make the program ill-formed.

> In Bloomington there was general agreement that given a class that uses non-static data member initializers, the exception-specification for the default constructor depends on whether those initializers are noexcept. However, according to 11.4 [class.mem] paragraph 2, **the class is regarded as complete within the brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members.**
>
> This suggests that we need to finish processing the class before parsing the NSDMI, but our direction on issue 1351 suggests that we need to parse the NSDMI in order to finish processing the class. Can't have both..
>
> **Additional note (March, 2013):**
> A specific example:
>
> ```
>  struct A {
>    void *p = A{};
>    operator void*() const { return nullptr; }
>  };
> ```
>
> Perhaps the best way of addressing this would be to make it ill-formed for a non-static data member initializer to use a defaulted constructor of its class.
>
> **Proposed resolution (February, 2014):**
>
> A brace-or-equal-initializer shall appear only in the declaration of a data member. (For static data members, see 11.4.9.3 [class.static.data]; for non-static data members, see 11.9.3 [class.base.init]). **A brace-or-equal-initializer for a non-static data member shall not directly or indirectly cause the implicit definition of a defaulted default constructor for the enclosing class or the exception-specification of that constructor.**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. So if I understand correctly, specifying the exception behaviour of the constructor for B should solve this e.g.:

```
class A
{
public:
  class B
  {
  public:
    int x = 0;
    B () noexcept = default;
  };

  static_assert (has_Default_Constructor <B>); // Now compiles ok

  B b;
};
```

It does now compile in gcc and clang.